# load data from xml to combobox using c#

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

i will load data from xml file to combobox using c#???code not run

**Code  :**

```
 private void GetIrama()
  DataAkses.EKG.Referensi referen = new DataAkses.EKG.Referensi(_conn);
        DataTable data;
        string msg;
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        int i = 0;
        string str = null;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("REF_IRAMA_DSR.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        xmldoc.Load(fs);
        ListItemPopup irm;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        cbiramadasar.Items.Clear();
        XmlNodeList colorList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("config/dataSources/dataSource");
        foreach (XmlNode dataSources in colorList)
        {
            cbiramadasar.Items.Add(dataSources.Attributes["DESCRIP"].Value.ToString());
        }
}
```

Comment: did you add break points and debugged your code to check if it is returning any value for XMLNodeList (colorList)?

Comment: still error this program

Comment: do not display in combobox